# deserializing json to c# object

Tags: c#, json

my C# is not well but I want to deserializing  this my json file to C# object:

```
[
{
    "command":"",
    "name":"eee",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "command":"Report",
            "name":"x",
            "children":[],
            "path":"wwwwww",
            "params":
            {
                "PeriodType":"1i",
                "District":"0i"
            }
        },...
    ],
    "path":"",
    "params":{}
},...
```

for this schema I have created this object:

```
[DataContract]
public class ListCommands
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Commands> commandList { get; set; }
    [DataContract]
    public class Commands
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string command { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string path { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "params")]
        public Params parameters { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Commands> children { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

and :

```
public class Params
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PeriodType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string District { get; set; }
}
}
```

and I am using this code for deserializing json to c# object:

```
public static void ReadJsonFile()
    {
        ListCommands comList = new ListCommands();
        //List<Commands> comList = new List<Commands>();
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/File");
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(root + "\\commands.json"))
            comList  = (ListCommands)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ListCommands)).ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

but unfortunately I got this error:

```
Additional information: There was an error deserializing the object of type Notifications.Contracts.ListCommands. Encountered unexpected character 'ï'.
```

Where is the problem?I have a json file and I want to read this file and then convert to the c# object.

Comment: Does https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2014/03/19/encountered-unexpected-character-error-serializing-json/ help?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know my parsing is right!! If it  be right I will try it.

Comment: Use Json.Net for deserialization. Even MS is using it, guess why ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo I use of  Json.Net and my problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

According suggestion of *@SirRufo*

**1-** I have used of **Json.Net** in this way:

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/File");
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(root + "\\commands.json");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var comList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

and above error gone.

**2-** By this link I could run previously code:
[enter link description here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2014/03/19/encountered-unexpected-character-error-serializing-json/)

```
One of the reasons for this could be that the input file that contains the JSON-encoded data is created with a binary encoding or it has a Byte Order Mark(BOM) byte sequence for a binary encoded file.
For e.g. The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF) in the beginning of the file.
**Note:** You will see this if you created a .JSON file(or a binary file) using visual studio.
```

Answer (score 0):

The data format for deserialization differs.

1. Change json data.

   {
   "commandList":[
   {
       "command":"",
       "name":"eee",
       "children":
       [
           {
               "command":"Report",
               "name":"x",
               "children":[],
               "path":"wwwwww",
               "params":
               {
                   "PeriodType":"1i",
                   "District":"0i"
               }
           }
       ],
       "path":"",
       "params":{}
   }]
   }

or 2. Change the deserialization target type

```
comList.commandList = (List<ListCommands.Commands>)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ListCommands.Commands>)).ReadObject(stream);
```